# Duplicate Type With Name ' '

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I think anything is broken. The Problem is not code related. Even if I am creating a new WPF Project and try to compile i get following error:

Error   1   Unknown build error, 'Duplicate type with name '' in assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.'     WpfApplication1

This happens on every WPF Application I want to build.

I tried repairing .NET Framework, Re-Install Visual Studio, Cleared Global Assembly Cache etc...

edit: C# Projects Only ...

Comment: seems you're targeting 2 different versions of the .Net Framework? make sure your project references are setup properly. Other than that, call a priest and exorcise your computer lol

Comment: Is that in a new *solution*? Good luck with your problem

Comment: yep completely new solution, happens only with C# WPF or ASP.NET/C# projects

Comment: Did you install different Versions of Visual Studio on this system?

Comment: nope had a complete new install last week - win 8.1 - office - visual strudio - drivers nothing else

Comment: What happens when you run VS as Administrator and then create a new project?  Same thing?  (Not logged on as Admin, but right-click and run as Admin...)

Comment: same problem. strange thing is 2 days before it worked and suddenly it doesn't anymore - no new installations or updates on whole computer.